# How can I format a regex capture string so it can be formatted with String.Format()?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a input string that is in a format that can be captured by regex. I then need to replace each capture of the input string with a {n}, where n is the number of the group of the capture.

My input string looks like this:

```
"When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its [HP]{mechanic:hp} remaining, its []{type:grass}-type moves inflict 1.5× as much [regular damage]{mechanic:regular-damage}."
```

My output string needs to look a bit like this

```
"When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its {0} remaining, its {1}-type moves inflict 1.5× as much {2}."
```

Currently, I have the capture down - 
`\[([\s\w'-]*)\]\{([\s\w'-]*):([\s\w'-]*)\}`

However apart from that I am buggered; I have no clue how to proceed.
For context, the {0} will be replaced with a HTML span, with the span class being a capture from the group, as well as the span value also being a capture of the group. ie,

```
<span class="mechanic:hp">HP</span>
```

or

```
<span class="type:grass">Grass</span>
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var index = 0;
    var input = "this FOO is FOO a FOO test";
    var pattern = "FOO";
    var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => "{" + (index++) + "}");

    Console.WriteLine(result); // produces "this {0} is {1} a {2} test"
}
```

Comment: I actually tried EXACTLY this, but index++ didn't increment.I'll give it another shot when I get back to my PC

Answer (score 0):

This will replace with {n}:

```
string input = "When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its [HP]{mechanic:hp} remaining, its []{type:grass}-type moves inflict 1.5× as much [regular damage]{mechanic:regular-damage}.";
string pattern = @"\[([\s\w'-]*)\]\{([\s\w'-]*):([\s\w'-]*)\}";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    input = input.Replace(matches[i].Groups[0].ToString(), "{" + i + "}");
}
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Output:

```
"When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its {0} remaining, its {1}-type moves inflict 1.5× as much {2}."
```

If you wish, you can use the following to replace with spans directly:

```
string input = "When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its [HP]{mechanic:hp} remaining, its []{type:grass}-type moves inflict 1.5× as much [regular damage]{mechanic:regular-damage}.";
//Note: Changed pattern to only have 2 match groups to simplify the replace
string pattern = @"\[([\s\w'-]*)\]\{([\s\w'-]*:[\s\w'-]*)\}";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    string spanText = matches[i].Groups[1].ToString();
    string spanClass = matches[i].Groups[2].ToString();
    input = input.Replace(matches[i].Groups[0].ToString(), "<span class=\"" + spanClass + "\">" + spanText + "</span>");
}
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Output:

```
"When this Pokémon has 1/3 or less of its <span class=\"mechanic:hp\">HP</span> remaining, its <span class=\"type:grass\"></span>-type moves inflict 1.5× as much <span class=\"mechanic:regular-damage\">regular damage</span>."
```